# A word for the property of scaling distance between two endpoints?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, academia

> Scalability is defined as the capacity to be changed in size or scale.

In Computer Science, the term is often used in a context such as scalable networks, scalable algorithms, etc. 
However, I want to use a word metaphorically similar to scalability, given the following situation.

> A system which is capable of providing real-time data over the network
>   where the distance between the sensor providing the data and the
>   receiver can be increased if required without noticeable effect on the
>   rate of transfer in given ideal conditions.

- Is there already a word for the above?
- Can I term it as space scalability?
- Would space scalability be correct to use in an academic context?

Comment: I’d call that “reliability”, “dependability”, “stability”, “unsusceptibility”, “range invariant”.  I wouldn’t consider it to be any form of scaleability though.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, however, I somehow want to emphasize on the ability to scale the distance which denotes a decoupling or isolation of the two endpoints.

Comment: I agree with Jim.  To me, *scalable* and *scalability* involve some sort of proportion.   The thing you're looking at doesn't.  How about *extensibility* and *extensible*?

Comment: @getchar -  But it’s just doing what it was designed to do within the design constraints.  My car is not scaleable because it can go to the store but also go to California.  It would be scaleable if I could swap in a bigger gas tank.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's the wrong word. Scale applies to the domain. In your case, you want the opposite - your system is independent of scale. You want *scale independence*.

Example - http://www.vermontcomplexsystems.org/research/publications/unknown2016constrained

> Constrained growth of complex scale-independent systems
>
> Scale independence is a ubiquitous feature of complex systems that implies a highly skewed distribution of resources with no characteristic scale.